# Private pods showing as .bundle file instead of framework

Tags: swift, cocoapods, testflight, resourcebundle

So I created a private podfile repository where I store my podfile with source linked to private pods (code below), I succsefully added source and pod lines into my Podfile and I was able to use this private SDK.

My problem is when I try to upload app to testflight I got an error saying that binary files are not permitted and indeed my archive contains .bundle file which I think shoudn't be there

Here is my podfile

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

s.name         = "HigoSDK.precompiled"
s.version      = "0.4.0"

s.summary      = "HigoSDK for iOS"

s.description  = <<-DESC
HigoSDK framework
                  DESC

s.homepage     = "homepage_url"
s.license      = "Summer Agency License"
s.author       = "Summer Agency"

s.platform = :ios, "13.0"
s.swift_version = '5.0'

s.source = { :http => "url/higo-sdk-0.4.0.zip" }

s.vendored_frameworks = 'Precompiled/HigoSDK.xcframework'
s.resource = 'Precompiled/HigoSDK.bundle'
s.static_framework = true

s.dependency 'RxSwift'
s.dependency 'RxCocoa'
s.dependency 'DifferenceKit'
s.dependency 'Kingfisher'
s.dependency 'Swinject'
s.dependency 'KeychainAccess'
s.dependency 'SwiftJWT'
s.dependency 'lottie-ios'
```

And here is the screen from archive where u can see HigoSDK.bundle in wrong file format  [image]

I'm new to swift development so I don't really know if I added this library correctly (propably not)